# Unknown argument error when creating record

Tags: prisma, prisma2

I'm encountering some interesting behaviour when using Prisma ORM. It is related to Prisma's generated types, and I've been skimming the docs trying to find out more, but there doesn't seem to be much info about generated types in there (please correct me if I'm mistaken). Here's the behaviour:

Say I have a model with two 1-1 relations (`Profile` in the example below):

```
datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

model User {
  id      Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  name    String
  profile Profile?
}

model Profile {
  id      Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  name    String
  userId  Int?
  user    User?  @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  photoId Int?
  photo   Photo? @relation(fields: [photoId], references: [id])
}

model Photo {
  id      Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  url     String
  profile Profile?
}
```

The following code works when creating a new profile:

```
const user = await prisma.user.create({ data: { name: "TestUser" } });    
const profile = await prisma.profile.create({
  data: {
    name: "TestProfile",
    user: { connect: { id: user.id } },
    photo: { create: { url: "http://example.com/img" } },
  },
});
```

... but this fails with an error:

```
const user = await prisma.user.create({ data: { name: "TestUser" } });
const profile = await prisma.profile.create({
  data: {
    name: "TestProfile",
    userId: user.id,
    photo: { create: { url: "http://example.com/img" } },
  },
});
```

The error is:

> Unknown arg `userId` in data.userId for type ProfileCreateInput. Did you mean `user`? Available args:
> type ProfileCreateInput {
>   name: String
>   user?: UserCreateNestedOneWithoutProfileInput
>   photo?: PhotoCreateNestedOneWithoutProfileInput
> }

Why is the second create-profile code invalid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prisma essentially generates two type definitions for a `create` query. This is implemented with a `XOR` type, which ensures that only one definition out of two is fully specified and passed to the query:

```js
export type ProfileCreateArgs = {
  /* ... */
  data: XOR<ProfileCreateInput, ProfileUncheckedCreateInput>;
}
```

The definitions are called checked and unchecked, the former using nested fields and the latter using raw ids:

```js
export type ProfileCreateInput = {
  id?: number;
  /* ... */
  user?: UserCreateNestedOneWithoutProfileInput;
  photo?: PhotoCreateNestedOneWithoutProfileInput;
}

export type ProfileUncheckedCreateInput = {
  id?: number;
  /* ... */
  userId?: number;
  photoId?: number;
}
```

Which basically means that you either provide all references as `connect`, `create` etc. relations (checked) or as raw ids (unchecked). You cannot mix the styles, this is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

On Next.js, I had to recompile things with `next dev` or `next build`. That's because the Prisma migration tool doesn't notify your on-going server.

Comment: There's already a great answer to the question. Why add noise?

Comment: This isn't noise. If the person faces the same issue and she's using Next.js, then this *adds information*.

Comment: If you are using a coding workflow that involves a compilation step, then *of course* you have to recompile before the changes you make to your code get reflected in the behaviour of the program. In my opinion, this has nothing to do with the question, which is why I downvoted.

Comment: It's not that clear. I was expecting Next.js or Prisma itself to automatically force a live reload when a migration was done. But that isn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

One thing as I searched up on this strange behavior was that this may happen when indeed there are some unknown properties.

The error message may show that the relation is causing the issue, but actually some other fields that are mistakenly passed, but do not exist in the schema.